# Broken link in the blog

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

Clicking here:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Results in:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This report linked at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6661540#6661540

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed this one. I had setup an archives page in the dashboard but apparently I had never published the page. Thus it was not visible to anyone. I have now published the page to make it active and the link should now work.

The About page is also unpublished, but a cursory glance shows that it is incomplete. I invite those who are running the Mathematica Blog to head into the dashboard and tidy up the About page with information on the stuff you'll be posting in your blog. Then we can publish that and ensure that it is likewise not a broken link.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Grace!

Comment: will do on point 2.